# Statement works in PgADMIN but not in PHP Script

Tags: php

This statement works in pgAdmin but not when run in a php script the php script can select all but can not update why is this?

```
UPDATE users SET password = '123123' WHERE email = 'random@random.com'
```

PHP code that doesn't work:

```
$sql = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE users SET password = '11111111111' WHERE email = 'test@outlook.com')");
$sql->execute(array());
```

PHP code that does work:

```
$sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users");
$sql->execute(array());
$fr = $sql->fetchAll(); var_dump($fr);
```

Comment: What happens when you try it? Post any errors in your question.

Comment: Post errors and PHP code in which you are using this statement.

Comment: Bet you a dollar that your PHP script and pgAdmin are running as two different users with different permissions.

Comment: @Sammitch or connection in php is not established at all :)

Comment: I make a "SELECT * FROM table" and it works but not an update and I don't get any errors in PHP?

Comment: @JohnArckai Show us PHP code or close that question.

Comment: $sql = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE users SET password = '11111111111' WHERE email = 'test@outlook.com')");
 $sql->execute(array());

Comment: $sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users");
  $sql->execute(array()); 
  $fr = $sql->fetchAll();
  var_dump($fr);

this works just above it.

Comment: @JohnArckai - you're not checking for errors, though - what is the return value of your `prepare` statement? Is there anything in `$dbh->errorInfo()` or `$sql->errorInfo()`?

Comment: Ok found the error at the end of the statment there is a closing open bracket at the end.

Comment: @JohnArckai Like I said in the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your update query you've got `)` at the end which will cause syntax error. Check it using eg. `$dbh->errorInfo()`.

Also, don't use `prepare()` for queries that don't use parameters. Instead use `query()` for `SELECT` and `exec()` for others.